# Que significa/hace -u al hacer un push en git

Tags: git, github, git-push

Por qué se utiliza el `-u` a la hora de hacer un `git push -u origin main`, ya que aparentemente haciendo un push con o sin el hace lo mismo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

La opción `-u` es una abreviatura de `--set-upstream`.

Esta opción se da la primera vez que se hace un `push` de una rama a un repositorio remoto, y añade a la rama información de "seguimiento". Básicamente sirve para que cuando más adelante hagas `git pull`, ya que esa orden no recibe parámetros, git pueda saber de dónde bajar los cambios. También servirá si haces `git push` sin más parámetros.

No es necesario volver a especificar `-u` en las operaciones `push` siguientes, pues la asociación de la rama con el remoto ya ha quedado guardada por git.

### Detalles técnicos de bajo nivel

Toda esta información git la guarda en una carpeta oculta (dentro de la carpeta de trabajo) llamada `.git`, en el fichero `.git/config` y la actualiza a través de las opciones que estamos explicando.

En concreto, la parte en que se asocia la rama `main` con el remoto `origin` quedaría grabada en una parte de ese fichero que se ve así:

```
[branch "main"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/main
```

Y cuál es la URL asociada al repositorio `origin` estaría en la parte del `.git/config` que se ve así:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:usuario/nombre-del-repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

A partir de esa información, cuando haces `git pull` sin parámetros, o `git push`, git sabrá lo que debe hacer, porque:

1. Mirará en qué rama estás en ese momento (eso lo consulta en `.git/HEAD` y encuentra que estás por ejemplo en la rama `main`)
2. Mirará qué remoto está asociado con esa rama (eso lo consulta en el fichero `.git/config`, en la parte etiquetada con `[branch "main"]`, y determina que el repositorio asociado es el llamado `origin`)
3. Mirará a qué url se refiere el repositorio `origin` (de nuevo consulta el fichero `.git/config` bajo el apartado `[remote "origin"]` y descubre la URL
4. Conectará con esa URL para descargar los commits remotos que no tengas localmente y los mezclará con la rama local (en caso de un `git pull`), o subirá los commits locales que no estén en el remoto (en caso de un `git push`).

**Nota**. Sería posible también asociar la rama local `main` con una rama que en el remoto tenga otro nombre. Para eso harías por ejemplo `git push -u origin main:otro_nombre`. Cuando no especificas esa segunda parte del upstream, se usará el mismo nombre que la rama local, por lo que `git push -u origin main:main` equivale a `git push -u origin main:main`.

Comment: Excelente el aporte, @abulafia. Lo único que creo que tienes que ajustar es la forma en la que se trabaja cuando los nombres de las ramas son diferentes. Hasta lo mejor de mi conocimiento, la sintaxis es así: `git push el-remoto referencia-local:referencia-remota`

Comment: @eftshift0 Gracias! He comprobado que tenías razón y he actualizado la respuesta (en la Nota final)

Answer (score 7):

`git push -u repository` Básicamente hace un `upstream` en cada actualización de la rama del repositorio enviada. En pocas palabras, hace un seguimiento de todos los cambios que la rama ha recibido.

En caso de que necesites información sobre estos comandos utiliza `git --help git` para una explicación de la gran mayoría de comandos git.

Answer (score 6):

La opción -u hace referencia al upstream. Cuando llamas a la opcion -u lo que haces es referenciar al repositorio remoto principal. Se usa cuando tienes varios repos remotos y quieres cambiar entre ellos. (Vease cambiar a bitbucket o gitlab en vez de github). Además, (como ha indicado @abulafia) cuando tienes solamente un repositorio, te sirve para asociar la rama con el remoto en cuestion.

Comment: No necesariamente has de tener varios remotos. La opción `-u` debe darse también aun si tienes solo uno, para asociar la rama con el remoto en cuestión.

Comment: Toda la razón, modifico mi respuesta.